# Performance issues and optimisation of a sql query with union and group by

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, union

I have a list of users that I want to group by certain criteria. Simplified, they are grouped by A, B, C, D, E.
The E column can have a value picked in this list : 000, 071, 072, 2C, 2D, 2M, 3M, 3D.
You can't regroup users that have a different value for E, except for the 000, 072 and 071 who can be grouped together (so the E in not in the group by clause for these users).
To do that, I did a first union looking like this (the real query contains several JOIN instead of just "users", but it just adds complexity and is useless for my question) :

```
Select A, B, C, D, E from users where E not in ('071','072','000') group by A,B,C,D,E
union
select A, B, C, D, group_concat(E) from users where E in ('071','072','000') group by A,B,C,D
```

Until now it got the job done. Recently we had to add a new column. This column represents how the user was added to our database. Before, it was always done automatically. Now it can be done manually, but by doing so, some columns are left empty, and E is one of them because E is from a table that we don't fill with the manual method. These users must be regrouped with the '000', '071' and '072' (because the default value when E is Null is '000').

So I imagined something like this :

```
Select A, B, C, D, E from users where E not in ('071','072','000') group by A,B,C,D,E
union
select A, B, C, D, group_concat(E) as E from 
    (select A,B,C,D, '000' as E  from manual_users
     union
     select A, B, C, D, group_concat(E) as E from automatic users 
     where E in ('071','072','000')
) as 000
group by A,B,C,D
```

Do you think the is a way to make it simpler? With my actual database this query is 150 lines long, I'm sure I could do it in an other way

Comment: Would `IFNULL()` and/or `COALESCE()` help?

Comment: @RickJames Funny you say that, I actually used it without thinking of performance at first :)

Comment: Would you care to share (ie, add it as an edit) the ifnull/coalesce solution and explain that it was much slower?